# How change background color of complete row in excel export of datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables, export-to-excel

Hi im trying to set a background color to a complete row in a excel document exported with datatables, By now, i can paint just one cell.

this is the code for the excel export, i iterate the column where is the value to validate and then change the color.

```
 $.extend( $.fn.dataTable.defaults, {
          responsive: true,
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
          buttons: [
          {
            extend: 'copy',
            text: 'Copiar',
            className: 'copyButton'
          }, 
          { 
            extend: 'excel',
            text: 'Excel',
            className: 'excelButton',
            customize: function ( xlsx ) {
                  var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
                      $('c[r=A1] t', sheet).text( 'INVENTARIO - '+document.getElementById('titulo').textContent) ;
                     $('row c[r^="A"]', sheet).each( function () {
                        // Get the value
                      var prueba='prueba' ;
                        if ( $( this).text() == '1' ) {
                           $(this).attr( 's', '15' );
                           //   $(this).text( 'CUSTODIA' );
                            console.log("ENTRO");
                         //   $('row c[r*="4"]', sheet).attr( 's', '15' );
                        }
                    });
              },
                exportOptions: {
                columns: [ 7, ':visible' ]
                },
          filename: function() {

                  return 'INVENTARIO - '+document.getElementById('titulo').textContent ;

            }

          }
```

This is what i´ve made[Excel with one cell painted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MivBk.png)

But i need to paint the full row.
Thanks any help or sugestion

Comment: From what I understand, `$('row c[r^="A"]', sheet)` this iterates over each cell instead of a complete row. What I would suggest is iterating over each row and then inside that make an iteration on each cell from that row and if the first row has a `1` (like the validation you currently have) then put a bool as true and paint every cell in that row with the color. It might not be the best solution, but I'm not sure how that export-to-excel works

Comment: @PietroNadalini thank you, i will try it and tell you how is going